# Getting string with one char repeated in c# easy way

Tags: c#

I want easy function like that:

```
string getStringWithCharAndLength(char ch, int l)
{
  //Some easy code
  //return ch+ch+...+ch(string with Length l)
}
```

Example:

```
string str = getStringWithCharAndLength('k',5);<br>
Console.WriteLine(str);// "kkkkk"
```

Note: not this kind of solution:

```
string getStringWithCharAndLength(char ch, int l)
{
   string str="";
   for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
      str+=ch;
   return str;
}
```

Comment: _I want an easy function_ .... Great! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was thinking that there was easy solution, but couldn't find it in google. So thanks for answers and i don't care your sarcasm @mituw16

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's trivial - there's a [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) that does it already:

```
string text = new string('z', 5); // "zzzzz"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`string` contructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx), so no need for a new method:

```
return new String(ch, l);
```

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.